# How would a North Korean say 고생 끝에 낙이 온다?

Tags: spoken-korean

How would a Korean speaker from the North say **고생 끝에 낙이 온다** in his native dialect?

Comment: [고생끝에 락이 온다](https://dprktoday.com/news/7822) or [고진감래](https://www.chosonsinbo.com/2017/08/08-18/). 고진감래 is used in both Koreas.

Comment: @guriguri welcome to the site. I don't suppose you live in [Guri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guri)?

Answer (score 1):

Korean          ⇾      North Korean
고생끝에 낙이온다 ⇾ 고생끝에 락이온다

The word which is similiar is 형설지공,고진감래 흥진비래,비극태래,전화위복